# Passing value to another jsp from dynamic table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Am working on project where  i need to display dynamic table using database. Am able to display table but while passing values to another page for editing table am getting problem. Am able to pass only first row of the table. Am using javascript for passing value. Please help me. This is what I have tried till now

```
<table id='tbl2' border="2">
       <thead>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td colspan="7" align="center" >Team Shift Roster</td></tr>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td>Date/Shift</td> <td>06:00AM - 02:00PM</td> <td>02:00PM - 10:00PM</td> <td>10:00PM - 06:00AM</td> <td width="130px">Weekly Off</td> <td width="130px">General Shift</td> <td></td></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>

            <%
          if(rs != null){ 
            while(rs.next()){
                %>
             <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;" >
                   <input style="border:0px; width:100px" name="dd" id="dd" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" readonly /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>" name="one" id="one"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(3)%>" name="two" id="two"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(4)%>" name="thr" id="thr"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(5)%>" name="fr" id="fr"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:100px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(6)%>" name="fve" id="fve"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="button" onclick="myFun()" value="Update"></td>
                </tr>

         <%     } }
              else { out.println("No Record Found"); }   %>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my Jscript function

```
<script>
    function myFun(){
      var v1 = document.getElementById("one").value; 
      var v2 = document.getElementById("two").value; 
      var v3 = document.getElementById("thr").value; 
      var v4 = document.getElementById("fr").value; 
      var v5 = document.getElementById("fve").value; 
      var dd = document.getElementById("dd").value; 
      window.location.href='DCM_UsrShiftUpdt.jsp?v1='+v1+'&v2='+v2+'&v3='+v3+'&v4='+v4+'&v5='+v5+'&dd='+dd;

}
</script>
```

Kindly response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs need to be UNIQUE. Use parentNode's siblings to gather the input values for the row the button is in

Comment: why so many **Am**?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is duplicate ids, use dynamic ids, lets take row id:

```
if(rs != null){
    int rowId = 1;
    while(rs.next()){ %>
   <tr>
       <td style="font-weight: bold;"><input style="border:0px; width:100px" name="dd" id="dd<%=rowId%>" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" readonly /></td>
       <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>" name="one" id="one<%=rowId%>"/></td>
        .... so on for other <td>
       <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="button" onclick="myFun(<%=rowId%>)" value="Update"></td>
  </tr>
<%
rowId++;
  }
}
```

JS

```
function myFun(rowId){
    var v1 = document.getElementById("one"+rowId).value; 
    //so on for the rest
}
```

P.S. avoid using JSP scriptlets and use JSTL instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now. I have done few changes in code and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be UNIQUE. Use parentNode's siblings to gather the input values for the row the button is in

```js
var buts = document.querySelectorAll("[value=Update]");
for (var i=0;i<buts.length;i++) {
  buts[i].onclick=function() {
    var cells = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells, parms = [];
    for (var i=0;i<cells.length-1;i++) { // stop at the button
      var input = cells[i].querySelector("input");
      parms.push(input.name+"="+input.value)
    }
    console.log(parms.join("&"));
  }
}
```

```html
<table id='tbl2' border="2">
       <thead>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td colspan="7" align="center" >Team Shift Roster</td></tr>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td>Date/Shift</td> <td>06:00AM - 02:00PM</td> <td>02:00PM - 10:00PM</td> <td>10:00PM - 06:00AM</td> <td width="130px">Weekly Off</td> <td width="130px">General Shift</td> <td></td></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;" >
                    <input style="border:0px; width:100px" name="dd" value="1" readonly /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="1" name="one"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="2" name="two" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="3" name="thr" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="text"  value="4" name="fr" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:100px" type="text"  value="5" name="fve" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="button" value="Update"></td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;" >
                    <input style="border:0px; width:100px" name="dd" value="1" readonly /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="1" name="one"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="2" name="two" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="3" name="thr" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="text"  value="4" name="fr" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:100px" type="text"  value="5" name="fve" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="button" value="Update"></td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;" >
                    <input style="border:0px; width:100px" name="dd" value="1" readonly /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="1" name="one"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="2" name="two" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="3" name="thr" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="text"  value="4" name="fr" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:100px" type="text"  value="5" name="fve" /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="button" value="Update"></td>
                </tr>

         </tbody>
    </table>
```